# Angularjs and Pdfkit - example of saving pdf to downloads

Tags: angularjs, node-modules, pdfkit

Can any share an example of using Angularjs and Pdfkit to save a file to the client downloads? I've got it rendering in the same window as the app, but need it as a pdf file. I'm assuming this is all done client side rather than the server side with the Pdfkit node module.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pdfkit, it's a An Angular wrapper for PDFKit.